# Set landscape orientation without locking sensor orientation

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I'm working on an application that has an inline video player. I need to reproduce the fullscreen behavior of Youtube.

When the user goes to landscape rotating the device I catch it via onConfigurationChanged and make the corresponding layout modifications.

However, I also have a button to set fullscreen. I need this button to go to landscpe (ergo, fullscreen) but don't lock the orientation change via sensor.

Here is what I'm currently doing on onConfigurationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (this.isLandscape(newConfig.orientation)){
        this.goToFullScreenMode();
    }else{
        this.goToInlineMode();
    }
}
```

And here is what I'm doing in the button but failing because it locks the Activity in landscape:

```
this.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

What I need is to go to landscape mode but allow the user to change back to portrait with the sensor, like Youtube does.

I can do it by just locking in landscape until the device is horizontal (by reading directly from the sensor) and then unlock the orientation again. I don't think this is the most "correct" way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greetings from the futuristic year of 2016.

The paths of life took me back to this same predicament on another Android application and I found out that the REAL answer to the problem was to simply add this...

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

...right after setting the orientation to the desired setting.

---

*Here lies my own previous answer*

> Due to a lack of answers and because I was not abale to solve this in
>   an elegant way I finally ended using an OrientationListener to get the
>   raw degrees of the device.
>
> With that I was able to release the user's orientation configuration
>   once the device was positioned like the actual layout.
>
> If someone is interested in having more info about it just let me
>   know.

Comment: In my environment, proposed solution didn't work well. As soon as I call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED) device rotation is changed (which is undesired) so I needed to use OrientationEventListener https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html#onOrientationChanged(int)

Comment: In my case the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23489227/8383332).  I am handling configurationChanged by my self and when I set the orientation to UNSPECIFIED it come back to the previous orientation and does not change to the desired orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **`layout-land`** directory in res and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

or else put this line in your activity tag in manifest file

> android:screenOrientation="landscape";

Comment: This does not fix my problem. I already manage layout differences. I need to change the orientation to Landscape without blocking it in Landscape.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Or in your manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name="Activity"    
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"    />
```

Comment: This will only lock the Activity in landscape. I need to change the orientation to Landscape without blocking it in Landscape.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in ur Manifest for your Respective activity

```
<activity
    android:name="YourActivityName goes here"    
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"    />
```

Comment: This will only lock the Activity in landscape. I need to change the orientation to Landscape without blocking it in Landscape.